# IE7+ Position:Fixed Z-index scroll doesnt work

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

hi I've created a fixed navigation bar/header at the top of a page with the content below. on all browsers, if i scroll on the page, the content goes under the fixed position nav bar EXCEPT for IE (no surprise there) How do i edit the CSS so this works?

```
<div class="navbar" style="width:100%; position:fixed; left: 3px; top: 0px; z-index:1;">
blah blah blah navigation
</div>

<div class="content">
whats up, im the content and im really long so i need to scroll
</div>
```

here is an example of the behavior that works in most browsers but not the IE's of the world.

http://myivyleaguer.com/media/satcenter.html

Comment: You're missing the last `;` in the inline style there.

Comment: thanks. that didnt fix it though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are forcing IE into quirks mode because you haven't declared a doctype (http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html).

If you add this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
```

to the very top of your HTML document then position:fixed will work as expected. That is the HTML5 doctype, short and gets the job done.

In order to get the fixed position to work in IE6 as well, you'll need to add this to your stylesheet (I'm assuming the inline stuff is just for your testing):

```
* html .navbar { position: absolute; }
```

See this page (http://ryanfait.com/position-fixed-ie6/) for an explanation.

Comment: i generally have css inline all over my code, does this cause potential problems, or is it just bad practice? mostly im too lazy to transfer to a seperate stylesheet

Comment: adding that doctype tag worked! but it also broke some of my other CSS. looks like i need to handle my css better.

Comment: If you were relying on IE being in quirks mode then yeah, you will find that the switch to standards mode may break a few things. It will be a lot less painful in the long run though (and your pages will render in competent browsers much more consistently).

Inline CSS doesn't by itself cause any problems, but it points to bigger issues. You'll find people banging on about the separation of content and style, but it really is for good reason and again will save you a lot of time and hair-pulling if all your styles are safely in an external stylesheet.